How can I change labeltext colors using R forestplot package?
As an example, I will use synthetic data for R forestplot. I want to color the variables of labeltext as blue and red respectively according to the fermenter/pathogen conditions of output_df$taxa. I would really appreciate if someone could give me an idea how to do it!
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(forestplot)

fermenters <- c("Taxon_A", "Taxon_B")
pathogens <- c("Taxon_C", "Taxon_D", "Taxon_E")

Mean <- c(0.25, -0.10, 0.35, 0.05, -0.20)
Lower <- c(0.10, -0.20, 0.15, -0.05, -0.30)
Upper <- c(0.40, 0.00, 0.55, 0.15, -0.10)
names_med_out <- c("Taxon_A", "Taxon_B", "Taxon_C", "Taxon_D", "Taxon_E")
Estimate <- c(0.3, -0.15, 0.4, 0.1, -0.25)
P_value <- c("0.03", "0.15", "0.01", "0.50", "0.10")

output_base_data <- tibble(mean = Mean,
                           lower = Lower,
                           upper = Upper,
                           taxa = names_med_out,
                           estimate = as.character(Estimate),
                           p_value = as.character(P_value),
                           ci_range = paste0("[", sprintf("%.3f", Lower), ", ", sprintf("%.3f", Upper), "]"))

output_header <- tibble(taxa = "Taxon",
                        estimate = "Estimate",
                        p_value = "P-value",
                        ci_range = "CI [Lower-Upper]",
                        summary = TRUE)

output_df <- bind_rows(output_header, output_base_data)

output_df %>% 
  forestplot(labeltext = c(taxa, estimate, p_value, ci_range),
             is.summary = summary,
             xlab = "95% Confidence Interval",
             txt_gp = fpTxtGp(title = gpar(cex=1.35),
                              ticks = gpar(cex=0.75),
                              xlab = gpar(cex = 1),
                              label = gpar(fontfamily="", cex=1.15)),
             hrzl_lines = list("2" = gpar(lty = 2), "7" = gpar(lwd = 1, columns = 1:3, col = "#000044")), boxsize = 0.15, alpha = 0.75)


You need to debug your code. Many errors...

@Edward I debugged it. Can you check again?

col = fpColors(text = c('black','blue','blue','red','red','red'))? Or do you want a more general solution?

You can color the rows by changing your_plot$col$text like this (using your data):
    ## store plot:
    the_plot <- output_df %>% 
      forestplot(...)
    
    ## determine row colors:
    row_colors <- ifelse(output_df$taxa %in% fermenters, 'blue', 'green')
    row_colors[1] <- 'black' ## for title row
        
    ## assign row colors to plot object:
    the_plot$col$text <- label_colors
    
    ## plot:
    the_plot



